# Почему в редактируемом циклом значении не сохраняются результаты итераций?

Tags: циклы, golang

Редактирую в цикле содержимое файла. После каждой итерации результат предыдущей итерации сбрасывается. В итоге играет только последняя итерация. Как сохранять результаты всех итераций?

```
for _, link := range arrLinks {        
    var regul = link + ".txt"
    myRegexp, err := regexp.Compile(regul)
    var new_fileWork = myRegexp.ReplaceAllString(string(fileWork), link)   // Редактируем.
}
var new_fileWorkB = []byte(new_fileWork)
```

Comment: [Потому что](https://golang.org/ref/spec#RangeClause) вы редактируете значение в link, что есть копия значения из массива, а не в самом массиве. [Используйте](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945030/change-values-while-iterating) arrLinks[index] для редактирования напрямую в массиве.

Comment: Решил так: Перед циклом помещаем редактируемое содержимое в переменную - var fileWorkStr = string(fileWork) , и в цикле редактируем уже эту переменную - fileWorkStr = myRegexp.ReplaceAllString(fileWorkStr, link) . Ошибка была в том, что в каждой итерации редактировалось первоначальное значение. Не смог тут переносы сделать, поэтому всё сплошной строкой написал.